# rvm 3.0.0 install fails with '__rvm_make -j8' error

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 3.0.0 on Mac OS 13 for a course and failing miserably.

Typing

```
rvm install ruby 3.0.0
```

into the Terminal returns

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/username/.rvm/log/1692442276_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The contents of the make.log file are

```
+__rvm_make:0> make -j8
BASERUBY = /usr/bin/ruby --disable=gems
CC = gcc -fdeclspec
LD = ld
LDSHARED = gcc -fdeclspec -dynamiclib
CFLAGS = -O3 -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -fno-common -pipe 
XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin22 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0
CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   
DLDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/davidyrueta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/libruby.3.0.dylib -compatibility_version 3.0 -current_version 3.0.0  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  
SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL = 
LC_CTYPE = 
MFLAGS = - --jobserver-fds=4,5 -j
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
In file included from debug.c:27:
./vm_callinfo.h:176:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'
        rp(ci);
        ^
./internal.h:95:72: note: expanded from macro 'rp'
#define rp(obj) rb_obj_info_dump_loc((VALUE)(obj), __FILE__, __LINE__, RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING)
                                                                       ^
In file included from debug.c:27:
./vm_callinfo.h:217:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'
    if (debug) rp(ci);
               ^
./internal.h:95:72: note: expanded from macro 'rp'
#define rp(obj) rb_obj_info_dump_loc((VALUE)(obj), __FILE__, __LINE__, RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING)
                                                                       ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [debug.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from compile.c:39:
./vm_callinfo.h:176:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'
        rp(ci);
        ^
./internal.h:95:72: note: expanded from macro 'rp'
#define rp(obj) rb_obj_info_dump_loc((VALUE)(obj), __FILE__, __LINE__, RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING)
                                                                       ^
In file included from compile.c:39:
./vm_callinfo.h:217:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'
    if (debug) rp(ci);
               ^
./internal.h:95:72: note: expanded from macro 'rp'
#define rp(obj) rb_obj_info_dump_loc((VALUE)(obj), __FILE__, __LINE__, RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING)
                                                                       ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [compile.o] Error 1
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

which I have no idea how to interpret. Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Per comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71610807/troubles-upgrading-from-ruby-2-7-to-3-0-error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-r) thread, I tried running the following commands

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

and then running the rvm install command.  Unfortunately, the original error persists.